# This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server message when running automation test using Edge

Tags: testing, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

I'm currently trying to run an automation test using Edge.

Edge is loaded successfully but the browser displays 'This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server' message and the test then fails.

The error displayed in Visual Studios is:

(Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:63262/' (SessionNotCreated))

The test works with no issues when using Chrome or Firefox.

Edge version is 121.0.2277.112 (Official build) (64-bit)

Selenium.WedDriver.MSEdgeDriver version is 120.0.2210.144 (which is the latest build)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Latest driver version has been installed but the issue continues.

Comment: Please download the matching version of Edge WebDriver 121.0.2277.112 and test again: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/?form=MA13LH. If the issue persists, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue.